# Add appointment funtionality for my django app using Google calendar API

Tags: python, django

i am working on django app where patient and doctor interact , i want to add appointment funtionality for patient.

Details:

1.The patient user should be able to see a list of all the doctors in the system

2.Each list item should have:
Profile picture
Name
A button “Book Appointment”

3.Upon clicking that button the patient user should see a form with following:
Required speciality
Date of Appointment
Start Time of Appointment
A confirm button

4.Each appointment will be of 45 mins
5.When user clicks on confirm a calendar event has to be created for the doctor user

6.On confirmation the patient should see a screen with the appointment details:
Doctors Name
Appointment date
Appointment start time
Appointment end time(to be calculated by the application)

here my code link :https://github.com/geetanshpardhi1/intern_task_1

Please help me to code.